# using Raty jquery plugin with rails 4.0 scaffold form

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jscript, raty

I'm trying to use [Raty](http://wbotelhos.com/raty) in my rails form "Reviews" by using `<script>$('#default').raty();</script>`. '1 2 3 4 5' shows up instead of actual stars. I have my jquery.raty.js file is in apps/assets/javascripts and the images for stars in apps/assets/javascripts/images. When I mouse over a number, the console displays:

> Started GET "/reviews/star-off.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-17 17:50:04 -0400
>   Processing by ReviewsController#show as PNG
>     Parameters: {"id"=>"star-off"}
>     Review Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "star-off"]]
>   Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms
>     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Review with id=star-off):
>     app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb:67:in `set_review'

It appears that it's trying to pull the image as part of the reviews controller...but it's really just an image for the jquery plugin. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If it helps, I had to do the following to get it to work properly for me:

```
$('#star').raty({
  starOn: '<%= image_path('star-on.png') %>',
  starOff: '<%= image_path('star-off.png') %>',
  path: '',
  scoreName: 'star',
  space: true 
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. Was it the path issue or what?

Answer (score 1):

Tell raty where the images are, like such:

```
<script>
    $('#default').raty({
      readOnly: true,
      halfScore: true,
      score: 3,
      path: '/assets'
    });
</script>
```

The code above is working for me, with my images inside the folder app/assets/images. I had a problem with paths myself.

On a relevant note: Inside assets, there's a folder called images and one called javascript and I think they should only hold what they claim. For example, the images folder should only have images inside while the javascript folder should only have javascript files inside. It makes it easier for others who look or work on your code to know where everything is.